# How do I convert uwsgi command line into a yaml file?

Tags: amazon-ec2, flask, uwsgi

How do I put the following command into a app.yaml file. I would like to know what am I doing wrong?

```
uwsgi --socket 127.0.0.1:3000 --file /home/james/james-api/runserver.py --callable app --processes 2
```

This is yaml file below:

```
uwsgi: 
  socket: 127.0.0.1:3000
  python-path: /home/james/james-api/
  callable: runserver:app
  processes: 2
  pidfile: /tmp/uwsgi.pid
  daemonize: /var/log/uwsgi.log
  master: 1
  workers: 2
  chmod-socket: 666
  auto-procname: 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was remove the --

```
uwsgi: 
  socket: 127.0.0.1:3000 
  file: /home/james/james-api/runserver.py
  python-path: .
  callable: app 
  processes: 2
  master: 1
  workers: 2
  chmod-socket: 666
  auto-procname: 1
  pidfile: /tmp/uwsgi.pid
  daemonize: /var/log/uwsgi.log
```